# if zip files are large like 500+MB then move_uploaded_file not working

Tags: ajax, file, upload, upload-max-filesize, move-uploaded-file

Zip file is large then

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$location)){ }
```

not working It no shows anything if file is not moved to directory.

I have also enabled in httaccess file, becuase I can not access php.ini file on my live hosting, I'm using localhost for now, so tell me solution for localhost and also for live server.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1500M
php_value post_max_size 1500M
php_value max_input_time 1600
php_value max_execution_time 1600
```

But still nothing is working.

If file is below 200 MB then it is moved files to directory successfully.
Please help me.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$location)){
        echo json_encode(array('done' => 1, 'message' => "Uploaded"));
        exit;
        } else {
        echo json_encode(array('done' => 0, 'message' => "Something went wrong"));
        exit;
      }
```